# How to access this function in my object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I have a function object:

```
var myObj=function(){

};

myObj.prototype = {
  availableColor: function(i){

      return "red_"+i;

  }

  getColor: function(){
    var c = availableColor('3'); //Error: availableColor is not a function
    ...
  }
```

}

When I call `availableColor(i)` inside `getColor()` function, I got error **availableColor is not a function**....

I also tried to use `var c = this.availableColor('3');`

and

`var self=this` in the constructor, then `var c = self.availableColor('3');`

But, none of these help. what is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myObj={
  availableColor: function(i){

      return "red_"+i;

  },
  getColor: function(){
    var c = this.availableColor('3');
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Another approach:

```
var myObj=function(){

};

myObj.prototype.availableColor = function(i){
      return "red_"+i;
  };
myObj.prototype.getColor = function(){
    var c = this.availableColor('3');
return c;
};

b = new myObj();
document.write(b.getColor());
```

Comment: Is there any workaround if I insist to use function instead of object?

Comment: @Mellon looks like you forgot to put comma after first method definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add methods to myObj, just do:

```
myObj.availableColor = function(i){
  return "red_"+i;
}

myObj.getColor = function(){
   var c = this.availableColor('3');
}
```

The way you use `prototype` will make `myObj` an constructor: `var o = new myObj()`. `myObj` won't have those methods.

Comment: Hi, the thing is I would like to make myObj an constructor. I would like to get rid of the problem when I am using myObj as an constructor.