# Prototype function declaration

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-framework

I have defined the function:

```
var Test = function(){

};

Test.prototype={

   getColor: function(){
         return "red";
   },

   createCar: function(){
      var color = this.getColor(); //ERROR: this.getColor is not a function
      ...
   },

   getCar: function(){
      return new CarFactory(1, this.createCar);
   }

}
```

As you saw, I have defined **three** **prototype** functions: **getColor()** , **createCar()** and **getCar()**.

Inside **createCar()** function I called **getColor()**,

In function **getCar()**, I use **this.createCar** as a parameter of **CarFactory** constructor. I got the error:

> "**this.getColor is not a function**"

in the above indicated place, why this error? How to get rid of this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access this function in my object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701503/how-to-access-this-function-in-my-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might not be making a `Test` object and invoking it properly. I pasted your snippet into a test page, then added:

```
var obj = new Test();
console.log(obj.getColor());
// Outputs 'red'
obj.createCar();
// Does not throw an error.
```

Replacing your `...` with `console.log(color);` revealed the correct result 'red' in my test.

http://jsfiddle.net/2F5zz

Comment: Hi, I updated my post. I did not describe my problem accurately.

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate `Test` correctly. Like this:

```
var test = new Test();
test.createCar();
```

You won't get this error. It seems to me that you are trying to call `createCar` this way:

```
Test.createCar();
```

When you define prototypes you are defining members that will be copied to any instance of that type/function. In your case, you are defining that every instance of Test will have the 2 functions, getColor and createCar. So, these functions are not on the Scope of Test. They are on the scope of instances of Test. You create instances with keywork `new`

Comment: Hi, I updated my post. I did not describe my problem accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Because with this.createCar as callback you are passing just the function without its context.

Try to change your code as follow:

```
   getCar: function(){
      var that = this;
      return new CarFactory(1, function() {
            return that.createCar();
      });
   }
```

Or just pass the Test instance to CarFactory and delegate to it the calling of createCar :P